# Computations on nodes via XPATH

Tags: xml, xpath

Let's say we have the following document

```
<elements>
    <el>
        <size>5</size>
        <price>10</price>
    </el>
    <el>
        <size>4</size>
        <price>16</price>
    </el>
</elements>
```

The task is to get a list with the quotient of size and price of every element.

I know, that division can be done via div, but

```
//el/size div //el/price
```

returns just the first result. How can I get all results?

Intended result:

```
0.5
0.25
```

Comment: If you're using XPath 2.0 try `//el/(size div price)`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Apparently I didn't use XPATH 2.0 for my tests, although I thought I did.